# What does the TFS "Online Team" icon modifier mean in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Most `.aspx` files in my Solution Explorer have a blue globe with a black paper sheet icon.

Some have a black globe with the ["Online Team" icon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186350.aspx#e9744fc1-86e6-4bb8-8919-8af27ff6752a) modifier:

[image]

What does the black one mean? These files are both checked in without locks.

Comment: Could you add a screen shot with full suffix?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. When I get back to work tomorrow. (I knew I was going to regret cropping it so much.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not reproduce your issue, in my side all the .aspx file is the blue globe with a black paper sheet icon. However the .ascx is the black globe with the "Online Team" icon modifier.

[image]

> .ASCX is Active Server Custom Control. It is used for creating custom
> controls in asp.net.
>
> [What Is .ascx control? And how to use this control In C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423730/what-is-ascx-control-and-how-to-use-this-control-in-c)

If it's another type of file, this is make sense for the mismatching icon. Maybe you just mix up the two files.

Comment: You were right! For some reason I assumed the ascx's would be in a different folder, but the black icons are indeed ascx files.